# Contact Form 7 Textarea styling

Tags: html, css, contact-form-7

community,

I already searched for a solution to this but I can't find anything that helps me with this issue.

The textarea on my WordPress-Page is always a couple of pixels longer than my other two fields and all I want is for them to be properly aligned.

I attached a screenshot and here is a link - it's the form in the footer area

http://relaunch.lieblingsbilder.net/

Can someone help me? Why is only the textarea not sizing properly?

[image: Contact Form 7 - Textarea]

Thank you for your help!

Edit:
CF7 Code:

```
    <label for="" class="">[text* your-name placeholder "Dein Name*"]</label>        <br />
    <br />
    <label for="" class="">[email* your-email placeholder "E-Mail-Adresse*"]</label>        <br />
    <br />
    <label for="your-message" class="">[textarea your-message x4 placeholder "Deine Nachricht"]</label><br />

    <center>[submit "Senden"]</center>
    <div class="indicates-required"><span class="asterisk">*</span> Pflichtfeld</div>
```

Comment: your link is not working

Comment: Oh sorry, I had a blank coming soon page on. Now it should work!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is your **`cols="40"`** in your **`textarea`**. To override this just put the below css code in your custom css file.

```
.wpcf7 input[type="text"],
.wpcf7 input[type="email"],
.wpcf7 input[type="password"],
.wpcf7 textarea {
  width: 100%
}
```

I hope this will work

Comment: Hi, actually, this kind of worked. I used this css in my WP "custom css" section and although the form is in a footer-widget, it only works on the main page. Why isn't it applied to every page? (How did the cols="40" get there in the first place?) Thank you.

Comment: This is because I have used `id` of that specific contact form. If you want this on all contact form you have to use `class` instead of `id` in css. check updated answer.

Comment: thank you, this works great. I had another field with the phone number so I added input[type="tel"] and it worked. Great!